# LaTeX + R как использовать нижнюю / верхнюю нумерацию букв в таблице

Tags: r, latex, tex

Всем привет. Нужно построить таблицу в **LaTeX** с помощью языка программирования **R**. Для этого я создал файл **mydata**, в котором содержатся следующие данные:

```
 r    n
4.17  1
6.67  2
9.09  3
16.67 4
```

Пример кода:

```
<<echo=FALSE,results = "asis">>=
library("xtable")
library("broom")
result <- read.table(file='mydata',nrows = 4,header 
=TRUE,encoding='utf-8')
M1 <- lm(n ~ r, result)
res <- tidy(M1,encoding="UTF-8")
example <- data.frame(res) 
example$term[1] <- 'n'
example$term[2] <-  'r'
print(
xtable(example),
include.rownames = FALSE,
include.colnames = FALSE,
add.to.row = list(
pos = list(0),
command = c("n1 &  n2 & n3 & n4 & n5\\\\"))
)
@
```

Мне надо получить в первом столбце таблицы, например:

```
n³
r²
```

Я пытался это сделать с помощью `example$term[1] <- 'n^3`, но в таблицы  получаю **n^3**. Как это реализовать?

Comment: `n^3` в LaTeXe вроде бы не так верхние индексы пишутся.

Comment: В **LaTeX** верхние индексы пишутся с помощью `$r^{2}$`. Я попробовал  `example$term[2] <- $r^{2}$`не помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите, как вообще эти штуки верстаются. Например, http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/SweaveLatex/fhsweaveEx.pdf

Comment: Я посмотрел. Многое непонятно, например, как строятся таблички, откуда берутся числа.